# How to set color theming with Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started using Twitter Bootstrap 3, and I am not familiar with any prior version of the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

I setup a basic WordPress theme using Twitter Bootstrap 3 as the framework. I have all my elements where I want them.

Everything is using blue colors for text shadowing, background colors, etc. I would like to keep all elements created on the theme to match that of the "dark style" (Similar to that of the inverted navigation bar colors).

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have a ton of CSS overriding to do? Are there color schemes or themes that can be loaded with Twitter Bootstrap 3 to override the default color of blue for everything?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PaintStrap](http://paintstrap.com/) to generate bootstrap themes using the color schemes.
Also, you can create layouts using [Layoutit!](http://www.layoutit.com) or [BootTheme](http://www.boottheme.com).